# How to reset the content of recycler view in calling activity using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

What I want to do: As user type something in edittext, a API call and show the response in recyclerview.

in OnCreate()

```
 usersData= ArrayList()

 resultRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
 resultRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(
                    this@MainActivity,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
 itemsAdapter=adapter(this@MainActivity,usersData)
 resultRecyclerView.adapter=itemsAdapter
```

in OnResume()

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
  override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    //....
  }
  override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    //.......
  }
  override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

     Log.v("Text is ",s.toString())
     val url="https://api.github.com/search/users?q="+s.toString().trim()+"+sort:followers"
     fetchData(url)
  }
})
```

Method for fetching data

```
private fun  fetchData(url: String) {

   val tag_string_req = "string_req"
   val strReq = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, Response.Listener<String> {
                response ->
                   Log.d(TAG, response.toString())

                   val builder = GsonBuilder()
                   val gson = builder.create()
                   //val allItems=gson.fromJson(response,AllUsers::class.java)

                   val data=gson.fromJson(response,AllUsers::class.java)
                   usersData=data.items

                   Log.v("No of users",usersData?.size.toString())

                   resultRecyclerView.removeAllViews()
                   itemsAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.message)
        })

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req)
}
```

But updated data is not passing in the adapter (it still have zero data). I getting the expected response from the `API`. `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not updating the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought notifyDataSetChanged also update the data automatically but no.

I need to call

```
    itemsAdapter?.updateData(usersData)
```

and in adapter:

```
fun updateData(users: ArrayList<Items>?){
        this.users=users
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in adapter

```
fun addData(exList: MutableList<Object>) {
    items.clear()
    items.addAll(exList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

and add data from your activity/fragment like this

```
 projectsAdapter.addData(list as MutableList<Object>)
```